# fwrite function round numbers

Tags: matlab, long-integer, fwrite, rounding

I would like to store data in to binary file (precision 'long' - manufacturer's requirement) but after reading file in another software, numbers are rounded. I figured out that when I try to read that file back in MATLAB, numbers are also rounded. Small example:

```
>> number=-3.913;
>> fid_out=fopen('test','wb');
>> fwrite(fid_out,number,'long');
>> fclose all;
>> fid_in=fopen('test','rb');
>> fread(fid_in,'long')

ans =

    -4
```

I am sorry, I am not so familiar with binary number type. The reason why I want to use 'long' is external software data decoder. Only information which I got is this:

[image]

Some clue?

Comment: If I understand that screenshot correctly, you'll probably have to write the first value as a double (Time) and the subsequent 6 values as longs. This could explain the discrepancy between the matlab and "decoder"-side numbers, where the first number is read correctly, while the rest is not.

Comment: @sebastian I have tried to figure out the problem only with bad writing of 'long' numbers after herohuyongtao's advice everything is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got rounded number because you are writing and reading using `long`, which is a 32 bit integer. To make it work, you need replace `long` by floating types like `double`, `float` etc.

```
number=-3.913;
fid_out=fopen('test','wb');
fwrite(fid_out,number,'double');
fclose all;
fid_in=fopen('test','rb');
fread(fid_in,'double')
```

You will get:

```
ans =

    -3.9130
```

---

**Edit:** If you have to use `long`, you can first multiple the numbers by a big scale number like `1000` to make it a `long` and at the same time don't lose the accuracy. Then when loading the data back, you can get the original values by further dividing them by the same scale.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Change of type helped in MATLAB but not in external software. Thanks

Comment: @JakubJon I did see your external software also support `double`.

Comment: For sure, it does. But instead of this: 569897.475 -3.913    -0.287    +8.990    +0.270    -0.059    -0.067 I got this: 569897.475 -1065718120.00000 -1097666134.00000 1091557130.00000 1049247089.00000 -1116624388.00000 -1115080884.00000 ..

Comment: @JakubJon Check out the updated answer if you have to use `long`.